# How to filter the output of ls command to display only files created in February?

Tags: linux, terminal, ls, superuser

For Linux OS, How to filter the output of ls command in terminal to display only files created in February?

Comment: It's an off-topic as it related to superuser.

Comment: try this: find Folder_name -type f -ls |grep 'Feb'

Comment: Although it is related to superuser, there are a lot of answers to question. I would go with `ls -l` ? `| grep Feb`.  I add the question mark because this will setup your time.  Here you can print based on modification time, creation time, etc.  It's up to you, read the man pages.

Comment: Don't parse ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
touch --date "yyyy-mm-dd" /tmp/start
touch --date "yyyy-mm-dd" /tmp/end
find /my/path -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end
```

or

```
ls -l  | grep 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Answer (score 24):

You can simple grep the output to filter out only Feb files

```
ls -l | grep "Feb"
```

If you want to filter out files in the sub directories also then

```
ls -l -R | grep "Feb"
```

**Note**

- R flag means recursive